# Use auto incremented ID in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two columns in my DB table, where the first one is auto incremented ID. In the second one I would like to have that ID mirrored. (I know it sound like design error, but I really need it)

Is it possible to configure it that way?

Comment: Create a view instead.

Comment: that do you mean with mirrored? it id is 12 the mirrored id is 21?

Comment: @RaymondNijland repeated. It is because I have two systems using that table and both need different column with exactly the same ID number.

Comment: You could use a trigger to set the value but you do need to be careful with triggers because if they fail, the insert typically fails.

Comment: Find a rubber duck and explain to it why the two systems can't use the same column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use TRIGGER

```
DELIMITER |:    # switch delimiter to prevent execution of  ;

CREATE TRIGGER `copy_id2c_name` BEFORE INSERT ON tb_name
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT INTO @AI FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'db_name' and table_name = 'tb_name';
set NEW.c_name = @AI;
END;

|:   # execute code
DELIMITER ;   // switch back original delimiter
```

Comment: doubt this trigger will work because the table name is the same on the trigger and update statement.

Comment: I tried 
`CREATE TRIGGER \`copy_id\` AFTER INSERT ON cargo__Wyklady
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE cargo__Wyklady SET _pageName = NEW._ID WHERE _ID = NEW._ID
END`
but it gives error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 4 `

Comment: Iswitch to BEFORE INSERT AND GRAB AUTO_INCREMENT  --- tested on mysql 5.7

Comment: Tried again: `CREATE TRIGGER \`copy_id\` AFTER INSERT ON cargo__Wyklady
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT INTO @AI FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'Cargo' and table_name = 'cargo__Wyklady';
set NEW._pageName = @AI;
END`

Cargo is db name.
cargo__Wyklady is table.
_ID is my auto incremented primary key.
_pageName is a column name where I'd like to have repeated _ID.

Am I doing it wrong? Error is `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3`

Comment: how do you create trigger --- if using shell then change delimiter

Comment: I do it in phpmyadmin. I click on database and I put code into SQL window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158519/discussion-between-bortunac-and-blaz).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MySql 5.7.6 or later you can define the second id as a virtual column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_mirrored INT UNSIGNED AS (id)
);
```

This way the id_mirrored column isn't really stored in your database but instead it's evaluated when the row is read.

If you're using an earlier version of MySql creating a view is probably your best option. Views are basically virtual tables.

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS 
    SELECT
        t.id AS id,
        t.id AS id_mirrored
    FROM my_table t
```

Third option is to define the id_mirrored as a real column and add a trigger to give it it's value. The way to do this has already been described in other answers.

Comment: I already have table with real column so I tend to third approach, but it still doesn't work for me. Anyway... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use smth like [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) in case you are using stored procedure.